# Runtime.exec() isn't working

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm trying to get the **radio logs** from Android device. I've found this snippet to read radio logs. However, the control never enters the `while` loop.

```
try {       
    String line = "";   

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat -b radio");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i("entered loop", log.toString());
        log.append(line + "\n");
    }
    Log.i("app", log.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

The code works fine if we replace the command as `adb logcat -d` as parameter to **exec()**.

I think the control is stuck in the **line = bufferedReader.readLine()** statement in condition.

EDIT:

Basically, I want to **read the notification** that is displayed on the screen. For example: The notification that we see after the call or sending SMS displaying remaining balance.

The notification is actually printed in the Android Logs and thus I am reading Logs and extracting the message from it. Is there any other way to store all notifications displayed on screen.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this code on a device, try replacing

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat -b radio");
```

with

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh" + "-c" + "adb logcat -b radio");
```

otherwise, try replacing it with (on linux)

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh" + "-c" + "adb logcat -b radio");
```

or (on windows)

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe" + "-c" + "adb logcat -b radio");
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing that line with::: Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe" + "-c" + "adb logcat -b radio");

Comment: Added Spaces but in vain...Not Working